# Generate all unique bank account numbers

Tags: c#

I have a method that checks if a number is divisible by 11.

```
public bool IsBankAccount(string BankNumber)
{
    int factor = 9;
    int restult = 0;

    try
    {
        if ((BankNumber.Length == 9))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BankNumber.Length; i++)
            {
                 restult += int.Parse(BankNumber.Substring(i, 1)) * factor;
                 factor -= 1;
            }
            return (restult % 11 == 0);

        }
        else
        {
            //Wrong length;
            return false;    
        }    
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {    
        return false;
    }    
}
```

But how to generate all the first bank account numbers that is a bank number, the first number is:

100000002 = because 9*1 + 8*0 + 7*0 +6*0 + 5*0 + 4*0 + 3*0 + 2*0 + 1*2 = 11

And if you want all the bank account numbers. THere are 1000 000 000 numbers in a 9 digit numbers. so 1000 000 000/11 = 90909090.9 11-eleven numbers

I just try different solutions.

but if I try this:

```
static readonly int[] multipliers = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var bansAsStrings = BANS().Take(100).Select(ban => ban.ToString());
            foreach (var ban in bansAsStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ban);
            }




            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static IEnumerable<int> BANS()
        {
            int[] digits = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 };


            int carryFlag = 0;
            do
            {
                int sum = digits.Zip(multipliers, (d, m) => d * m)
                                .Sum();

                if (sum % 11 == 0)
                    yield return sum;

                int digitIndex = digits.Length - 1;
                do
                {
                    digits[8] += 1 + carryFlag;
                    if (digits[8] == 10)
                    {
                        digits[digitIndex--] = 0;
                        carryFlag = 1;
                    }
                    else
                        carryFlag = 0;
                }
                while (carryFlag == 1 && digitIndex >= 0);
            }
            while (carryFlag == 0);

            yield break;
        }
```

the output is 11 100 times.

I have it now like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int linesPerFile = 10;
            const string destinationFileName = @"G:\Folder\File-Part-{0}.txt";
            //string fileName = "File";


            foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(200))
            {



                var fileCounter = 0;
                var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
                try
                {

                   // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                    //{
                        var lineCounter = 0;
                        string line;

                        while ((line = destiNationFile.NewLine) != null )
                        {
                            if (lineCounter >= linesPerFile)
                            {
                                lineCounter = 0;
                                fileCounter++;
                                destiNationFile.Dispose();
                                destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));

                            }

                            destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                            lineCounter++;
                        }
                    //}


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }


            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

But now every time it writes the first value: 1000 000 02

I have it now like this:

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    const int linesPerFile = 10;
    const string destinationFileName = @"G:\Folder\File-Part-{0}.txt";
    //string fileName = "File";
    var maxNumberOfFiles = 20;            



        var fileCounter = 0;
        var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
        try
        {

            // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
            //{
            var lineCounter = 0;
            string line;

            while (fileCounter < maxNumberOfFiles)
            {
                foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(200))
                {
                    if (lineCounter >= linesPerFile)
                    {
                        lineCounter = 0;
                        fileCounter++;
                        destiNationFile.Dispose();
                        destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));

                    }

                    destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                    lineCounter++;
                }

                fileCounter++;
                //}


            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }



    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But I dont like that you every time have to calculate the number of MaxFiles. Is there an other way to go? Thanks

Here is an update:

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    const int linesPerFile = 10;
    string path = @"G:\Folder";
    const string destinationFileName = @"G:\Folder\File-Part-{0}.txt";
    //string fileName = "File";
    var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



        var fileCounter = 0;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
           DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
        try
        {

            // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
            //{
            var lineCounter = 0;
            string line;

            while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
            {
                timer.Start();
                foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                {
                    if (lineCounter % linesPerFile == 0)
                    {
                        //lineCounter = 0;
                        destiNationFile.Flush();                                
                        destiNationFile.Dispose();
                        destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
                        fileCounter++;
                    }

                    destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                    lineCounter++;



                }

                fileCounter++;

                //}


            }


            timer.Stop();
            // Console.WriteLine(BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }



    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But to get the file names, like this: Nr[first number in file]-[last number in file].txt Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            const int linesPerFile = 10;
            string path = @"G:\Folder";
            const string destinationFileName = @"G:\Folder\File-Part-{0}.txt";
            var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
            var counter = 100;
            string tempFile;
            //string fileName = "File";
            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



                var fileCounter = 0;

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                   DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
                try
                {

                    // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                    //{
                    var lineCounter = 0;
                    string line;

                    while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                    {
                        timer.Start();
                        foreach (var bank in bans)
                        {
                            if (--counter == 0)
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                                if (lineCounter % linesPerFile == 0)
                                {
                                    //lineCounter = 0;
                                    destiNationFile.Flush();
                                    destiNationFile.Dispose();
                                    destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(destinationFileName, fileCounter + 1));
                                    fileCounter++;
                                }

                                destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                                lineCounter++;





                            fileCounter++;

                            //}


                        }
                    }


                    timer.Stop();
                    // Console.WriteLine(BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Count());
                    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }



            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

but then every time the last file of the ten files is empty.

And how to get the file names?

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        const int linesPerFile = 10;
        string path = @"G:\Folder";

        //string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
        var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
        string tempFile;
        const int MAX_FILES = 10;
        const int BANS_PER_FILE = 10;
        int bansCounter = 0;
        var part = new List<int>();
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);

        var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



            var fileCounter = 0;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
               DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            //var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
            try
            {

                // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                //{
                var lineCounter = 0;
                string line;

                while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS)
                    {
                        part.Add(bank);
                       if(++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                        {
                            //string fileName2 = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                            var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                            //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                            Console.WriteLine("NR{0}", fileName);
                            foreach (var partBan in  part )                                
                                Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                            part.Clear();
                            bansCounter = 0;

                            if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                           break;



                            //lineCounter = 0;
                            //destiNationFile.Flush();                                
                            //destiNationFile.Dispose();
                            //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                            //fileCounter++;
                        }

                        //destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                        //lineCounter++;



                    }

                    //fileCounter++;

                    //}


                }


                timer.Stop();
                // Console.WriteLine(BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Count());
                Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }



        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: `1000000002` has a length equal to 10, whereas the expression on the right is applied to a 9-digit number.

Comment: Why can't you just start with `1000000002` and increment it by `11` hundred times?

Comment: Typically, you would just increment over the first `n-1` digits, and the last digit is calculated to match your checksum.  However, this would not be a 1:1 projection with a mod 11 checksum, since 1 out of 11 strings cannot be made acceptable with a single digit.

Comment: Sorry one 0 to much, I edit my  post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> BANS
{
    get
    {
        int[] digits = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 };

        int carryFlag = 0;
        do
        {
            int sum = digits.Select((d, i) => d * (9 - i))
                            .Sum();

            if (sum % 11 == 0)
                yield return digits.Aggregate(0, (accumulator, digit) => accumulator * 10 + digit);

            int digitIndex = digits.Length - 1;
            do
            {
                digits[digitIndex] += 1;
                if (digits[digitIndex] == 10)
                {
                    digits[digitIndex--] = 0;
                    carryFlag = 1;
                }
                else
                    carryFlag = 0;
            }
            while (digitIndex >= 0 && carryFlag == 1);
        }
        while (carryFlag == 0);

        yield break;
    }
}
```

`Console.WriteLine(BANS.Count())` gives 81818182 BAN's. The calculation time about 5 minutes in the virtual machine.

First 10 values are:

```
foreach (var ban in BANS.Take(10))
    Console.WriteLine(ban);
----------------------------------
100000002
100000010
100000029
100000037
100000045
100000053
100000061
100000088
100000096
100000118
```

On the second question:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int MAX_FILES = 10;
    const int BANS_PER_FILE = 10;

    int filesCounter = 0;
    int bansCounter = 0;
    var part = new List<int>();
    foreach (var ban in BANS)
    {
        part.Add(ban);

        if (++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
        {
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}.txt", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Filename '{0}'", fileName);
            foreach (var partBan in part)
                Console.WriteLine(partBan);

            part.Clear();
            bansCounter = 0;

            if (++filesCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Privet Mark, but how to use threading ? that it goes little bit faster, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var bankAccounts = new List<string>(100);
for(long i = 100000000; bankAccounts.Count < 100;i++)   
{
    var stringNumber = i.ToString();
    if (IsBankAccount(stringNumber))
        bankAccounts.Add(stringNumber);
}
```

This can be also done with LINQ as follows.

```
var accounts = Enumerable.Range(100000000, 2000) // 2000 is a guess, there's sure 100 values divisible by 11 in that range
                         .Select(n => n.ToString())
                         .Where(IsBankAccount)
                         .Take(100)
                         .ToList();
```

As there are only numbers in bank account, you could probably do it without string conversions and string operation.

To get all of them, replace 2000 with 899999999, but it will take a long time to finish even if you do it `.AsParallel()` because the algorithm is really ineffective.

Based on a comment from ie, a fast algorithm could look like this, but it's still very memory consuming.

```
var nums = new List<string>();
for (int i = 100000002; i < 1000000000; i += 11)
    nums.Add(i.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you Ondrey, for you reply, I have edit my answare.

Comment: @Nielsfischerein I see, is that a question or just a stament? Do you need to solve another problem or is my solution enough?

Comment: (at)Ondrej  it has to be all the bank account numbers out of 9 numbers. thank you

Comment: Yes, ok, that Is why I search for a quick response time. it takes like 20 minutes, isnt. But ok, thank all the the solutions

Comment: (At) Ondrej, but what is then a better algoritme? Thank you

Comment: @Nielsfischerein For example take the number 100000002 and add 11 until you are over 1000000000 as mentioned in comments. I posted the solution to my answer, it's much more faster.

Comment: @Nielsfischerein All the numbers it generates are different ;)

Comment: ofcourse it is 1 000 000 000. But how did you calculate the number: 899999999 - for all numbers? in fact you can have 1 000 000 000 - 1 numbers so: (1 000 000 000 -1)/11 ~ 90909090

Comment: @Nielsfischerein But (1 000 000 000 -1)/11 also includes number like 11, so numbers shorter than 9 digits. 899 999 999 is used because when you start on the first 9-digit number 100 000 000, you want to end on the last 9-digit number and it's 100 000 000 + 899 999 999 = 999 999 999. Understood?

Comment: oke, but in your code you have: 1000000000 = it is nine nulls. so that has to be: 1 000 000 000 -1(because of the first 11) isnt? so: 999 999 999

Comment: @Nielsfischerein You mean this `i < 1000000000;`? It's on purpose. This number won't be processed. You can either write `i < 1000000000;` or ``i <= 999999999;`` it's the same.

Comment: Hi Ondrej, ok understand. But you see the solution that Mark posted. He has a point. That in the IsBankAccount you have to cast every time from string to int. but he is using: digits[i]. But where is the i initialized? Dont understand that. Maybe you know it.

Comment: @Nielsfischerein It's missing, he probably forgot to include it.

Comment: How can I hit three solutions as working, yours and Marks and from Mitch

Comment: @Nielsfischerein you can't

Comment: that is a pittie. But so the answare of all bank accounts is: 81818182. so not: 1000 000 0000-1/11. I dont understand where the number  81818182 is comming from

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the possible numbers by calculating the last digit as a check digit:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var num in GetMod11Sequence(10000000, 100000000).Take(100))
    {
        if (!CheckMod11CheckChar(num))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetMod11Sequence(int start, int stop)
{
    //Contract.Requires(start > 0);
    //Contract.Requires(stop > start);
    //Contract.Requires(stop < 1000000000);

    for (int c = start; c < stop; c++)
    {
        string number = c.ToString();
        char check;
        if (TryCalculateMod11CheckChar(number, out check))
        {
            yield return number + check;
        }
    }
}

private static bool CheckMod11CheckChar(string number)
{
    //Contract.Requires(number != null);
    //Contract.Requires(number.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)));

    int factor = number.Length;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
    {
        int cval = number[i] - '0';

        sum += cval * factor;
        factor--;
    }

    return sum % 11 == 0;
}

private static bool TryCalculateMod11CheckChar(string number, out char checkDigit)
{
    //Contract.Requires(number != null);

    int factor = number.Length + 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
    {
        int cval = number[i] - '0';

        sum += cval * factor;
        factor--;
    }
    //Contract.Assert(factor == 1);

    int delta = sum % 11;
    if (delta == 1)
    {
        // I cannot add 10, so this number is unavailable
        checkDigit = '!';
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (delta == 0)
        {
            checkDigit = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            checkDigit = (11 - delta).ToString()[0];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mitch, thank you for you response. but I implmented your solution. But I get the number: 1000 000 29 = 20. I mean also you get numbers who are not mod 11

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand.  `1 0000 0029` would be `1 * 9 + 2 * 2 + 1 * 9 == 9 + 4 + 9 == 22`;  `22 % 11 == 0`.

Comment: sorry you are right. But there are also double values, for example: 100000037 is the same as: 1000 00029. Both are 22

Comment: I don't understand why that would be a problem.  The checksum is only to verify integrity, not for use as a hash.

Comment: It has to be unique, values, but ok, I will look that I do it by myself. thanks

Comment: But why you have 100 000 000? is it not: 1000 000 000

Comment: No, because I am enumerating all 8 digit numbers, and adding the check-digit for the ninth.

Comment: ok, understand, so for all the numbers I can just use: take(899999999)? foreach (var num in GetMod11Sequence(10000000, 100000000).Take(899999999)) - I tried that. But it takes long time(more then 30 minutes). YOu have seen the solution from Mark - but he says, somewhere digits[i]. but where is the i initialized? you know that? Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do which requires all of the numbers?  To store them you would take multiple gigabytes. (and you can omit the `Take(int)` to get all of them)  If you are printing them to the console, that will be the slowest step.

Comment: I want them to safe them in file system. But I just firt test it in console version